# Clean URLs work*, but not when I submit forms?

Tags: users, forms, uri

I have a local dev site configured (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS), and I copied a production website to play with there. Everything appears to work great. Clean URLs seem to work and I can navigate the site. It's all wonderful... until I try to login.

When I login at /user, submitting the form returns me to the login as if nothing happened. I was able to login by visiting /?q=user .

After that, if I attempt to clear the cache under performance settings, I get a similar result where the performance page loads as if nothing happened (clearing cache manually via mysql doesn't help). If I disable clean URLs altogether, all is well.

I tried replacing the .htaccess file with Drupal's default to prevent special config issues (no effect). I didn't see anything set as $base_url in settings.php (I'll try setting that to see what happens next).

Any thoughts on why a site with clean URLs enabled seems fine until POST data is involved? Thanks for the feedback in advance!

Comment: update:
If I visit /?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls, and run the clean URL test, it fails. 


If I visit /admin/config/search/clean-urls, I can see the page. However, if I check "Enable clean URLs" then submit the form, the page reloads with the form option unchecked (same issue, but interesting). By following the handbook [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/15365), so far I can confirm that .htaccess files are read if I enter a bunch of random characters (which successfully breaks any page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to enable Apache's rewrite module using `a2enmod rewrite` or with sudo if you get permission errors and added the Apache directive `AllowOverride All` for VirtualHost.

Comment: ```sudo a2enmod rewrite```

"Module rewrite already enabled", let me double check my virtual host settings but I'm pretty sure that's all set to go. I can say that my .htaccess file is being read so far...

Comment: In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
    ...
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ...
    AccessFileName .htaccess
    ...
    

    In /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:
    
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ...
    </VirtualHost>

Comment: Sorry, guessing formatting is not working well in comments or I'm doing terrible pre-lunch. http://pastebin.com/9mByvybV

Comment: Oh gosh! Lunch fixed it, but I'm giving you the points. ;) When I ran <?php php_info(); ?>, I did not see mod_rewrite being loaded. While I thought I was restarting apache, it kept saying "[fail]" as I wasn't using sudo... After lunch, I REALLY restarted the server from efforts early morning and all worked like a charm.

Comment: That's good news! Great you got it working.

Comment: just moved my drupal install to a new server and that was exactly what I was missing from my config, Working great now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment `RewriteBase /` (remove #) in `.htaccess` file and make sure that `$base_url` in `settings.php` file is commented.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. With RewriteBase / uncommented, and $base_url commented out, I have the same results.